# Huge space between title and plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a issue with matplotlib that generates a plot(graph) very far from the title. My code is:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csvpath, delimiter=',', 
                     index_col=0, 
                     parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, 
                     names=['Date','test1'])

df.plot(subplots=True, marker='.',markersize=8, title ="test", fontsize = 10, color=['b','g','g'], figsize=(8, 22))

imagepath = 'capture.png'

plt.savefig(imagepath)
```

An example of the graph generated is:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Not sure what's missing here. Do you need a sample .csv? Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can adjust the title location by grabbing the `figure` object from one of the 3 `axis` objects that is returned in an array from `df.plot`.  Using `fig.tight_layout` removes extra whitespace, but a known problem is that is also sets the figure title within the top plot.  However, you can fix that using the last line below.

```
ax = df.plot(subplots=True, marker='.', markersize=8, 
             title ="test", fontsize = 10, color=['b','g','g'], 
             figsize=(8, 22))[0] 
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and explanation, it works! Just one question, why do you use the [0] at the end of the ax = ? Thank you again.

Comment: The `plot` function returns an array of axes, in this case 3 axes.  Using `[0]` selects the first one.